# query string and parameter map in the redirected url is null

Tags: java, servlets, request, httprequest

I'm writing a plugin for nexus oss, where I am doing a `response.sendRedirect` as follows

```
String redirectUrl = url + "#nexus-search;gav"
    + "~net.collab.builds~teamforge~~~~"
    + "?" + req.getQueryString();   

response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(redirectUrl));
```

the redirect url formed will be like

```
http://domain/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;gav~net.collab.builds~teamforge~~~~?sfId=prpl1106&sfLoginToken=A237421CF755183D177F5C020752040F&isLoggedIn=true
```

What I am doing here is append the query string that was present in the old request object and appending to new url and redirecting to it.

But what I cannot understand is thought I have the query string in the `redirecturl`
I am not getting the query string when the new redirected url is hit. 
I put break point and found that after the redirect url is done and when it is processed the query string is null.

**Following are the doubts :**

1) What did I do wrong which made query string vanish ?

To see if the redirect happened well, I did `request.getCookie` and found that the cookies were present as it was in the old request. So where am I going wrong? Where did my query string of the new url go?

2) Will the redirected url also have the `paramterMap` that was there in the old request object. At present the `paramterMap` is also null in the redirected url. Should I explicitly get from old request object and put it in response during redirecting. How can I make the parameter map in the old request object also be sent in redirecting process.

**Update of my debugging:**

When I access url with #nexus like something strange is happening.

I have logged it in jira as an [issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6023) in nexus oss .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya found the solution.

The problem is regarding where the query string is appended . In code I appended the query string after the fragment(part following the # symbol) .From searching I found

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5

so this means the fragments will not be considered while generating request objects . They are in fact jettisoned .

So the solution would be to **append query string at the right place. To be precise append it before the fragments .**

```
String redirectUrl = url + "?" + req.getQueryString(); + "#nexus-search;gav" + "~net.collab.builds~teamforge~~~~" ;
```

So this solves my problem .
Hope it will be useful for others who commit the same error.
Thanks